# How to place a div on a different layer?

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

CSS

```
#div1{
    height:50px;
    visibility:hidden;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

#div2{
    margin-top:70px:
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function switch01(){
    $("#div1").slideToggle("slow");
};
```

I expected that `#div1` overlaps `#div2` during sliding, because of its higher z-index. Something like on a different layer. But instead, `#div1` pushed `#div2` down increasing its top margin.

Comment: For this effect you should use position the elements  absolutely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to absolute positioning

```
#div1{
height:50px;
visibility:hidden;
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
}

#div2{
margin-top:70px:
position:absolute;
z-index:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the "overlapping" effect you want you need to remove the sliding element from the flow of the layout.

This is acomplished by setting the `position` to either `absolute` or `fixed`

Here is a working example of what you want to do...

HTML

```
<a id="button" href="#">Click me!</a>
<div id="div1">Slides on Top</div>
<div id="div2">Rests in bottom</div>
```

CSS

```
#div1 {
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
}

#div2 {
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

JS

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    $("#div2").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

More on the `position` attribute [Click here](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/).
Hope it helps!